# Node.js unable to display the text file from a link on webpage

Tags: node.js, html

I am trying to display the link to a text file on the local machine using node.js. While, the file is being read properly, the link is not working. It says, "FILE NOT FOUND".

**Snippet of code:**

```
file = (doc[0].filename)
fs = require('fs');
var varname ='/home/mingupta/test/public/coords/'+file;
var varname1 = '/home/mingupta/test/public/coords/'+file;


fs.readFile(varname,'utf8',function(err,data){
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else{
        res.send('<a href=\"'+varname1+'\">'+file+'<\a>'+'<br>'+'Contents:'+'<br>'+data);
    }
}
```

What changes are to be made in the file path?

Comment: Could you please show me doc[0].filename result, I think it might be an extension error, extension might be not added

Comment: The extension is read correctly, because the contents of the file are displayed on the webpage. However the link doesn't open the text file.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your developer tools you will find a message in the console says

> Not allowed to load local resource: file:///...

If you need to allow loading local resources try the following comands

You need to use both arguments. This is how I run it on my mac.

> open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security
>   -–allow-file-access-from-files

This is how it should be for windows:

> "C:\PathTo\Chrome.exe" –allow-file-access-from-files
>   -disable-web-security

It is not the best approach here, you have to make a real URL for your files to be served over the internet then your click will work properly.